# Ruby On Rails: Instagram gem, unable to reach callback url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, real-time, instagram

I've been seeing some interesting behavior with the Instagram gem and realtime API, I am trying to create a basic app to create subscriptions and process Instagrams' response. Below is the code to create the subscription and save the tag name to my db.

```
  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new params[:subscription]
    options = {:object_id => params[:subscription][:tag_name]}

    if @subscription.save
      Instagram.create_subscription('tag', "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/subscriptions/process_subscription/", aspect = 'media', options)
      redirect_to "/subscriptions/tag/#{@subscription.tag_name}"
  end
```

Notice the callback url is at heroku which is reachable, the interesting thing is that when I go to `subscriptions/new` at the heroku domain the Instagram API gives me a "Bad Request, Unable to reach callback URL". When I create the subscription over curl with the same callback url everything works as expected, when I go to `subscriptions/new` on my localhost (with the same callback url set) it also works as expected. Below is the process_subscription action:

```
def process_subscription
  if params["hub.challenge"]
    render :text => params["hub.challenge"]
  else      
    PrivatePub.publish_to("/subscriptions/tag/#{params[:object_id]}", payload: params[:_json])
  end
end
```

The first if statement will take care of the pubsubhubub challenge. Once the subscription is actually created I don't have a problem receiving and processing the payload. So right now the only thing I can think of is when i'm at the heroku domain the server process is somehow busy when Instagram posts back to it, I don't understand how that would be possible so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to the server logs when a subscription is successful and when it fails. Note, I was logging out the post params in these logs. https://gist.github.com/4256108.

Answer (score 5):

After much trial and error, the problem was looking more and more like the rails process was busy when Instagram sent its' hub.challenge back to the app resulting in the "Bad Request, Unable to reach callback URL" error.

What worked for me was using another thread to create the Instagram subscriptions, this way Instagram can successfully hit my app almost instantaneously and reach my callback url. This solution was the quickest and most lightweight, perhaps It would be beneficial to purchase one or so workers on Heroku and move this into a background process via Sidekiq or something but that seems a bit overkill for just responding to a hub challenge.

```
  def instagram_photos
    Thread.new do |t|
      options = {:object_id => params[:tag_name]}
      Instagram.create_subscription('tag', "http://myapp.herokuapp.com/subscriptions/process_subscription", aspect = 'media', options)
      t.exit
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

Comment: In addition to this Thread method, a better solution is to use a server like Unicorn that handles concurrent processes by default.